# Making a Chrome plug-in of Suricata/Snort for intrusion detection on client side

Tags: browser-plugin, snort, intrusion-detection, client-side-attacks

I want to use Suricata turning it into a Chrome browser plugin for internet based intrusion detection. Specifically, I want to detect/prevent malicious attack of access to cache data.